# Is it possible to restrict the number of connections for a role/login in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, security, connection

e.g. Make it so that you could limit it to a max 2 connections for a given technical account, the third connection being blocked repeatedly until one of the others is given up

Comment: It's question for ServerFault :)

Comment: Serverwhat? Tried searching the site for it. Tried using google to do the same thing with a site: modifier. Nada. No single clear explanation as to what it is/does/eats.

Comment: I hope you've found it by now, but just in case: http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes but you need a tiny bit of SQL code. You can enforce any policy you like by creating a [Logon Trigger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326598(SQL.90).aspx). This trigger is new to SQL Server 2005 SP2 (it is **not** in RTM version afaik) and is run every time a connection is established, before any statement is accepted from said connection. Make sure you use a proper EXECUTE AS clause for your trigger. In the trigger you can inspect sys.dm_exec_sessions and sys.dm_exec_connections and decide if the new connection is allowed yes/no. Pleas note that on SQL 2005 the number of sessions is not necessarily equal with the number of connections, because of [MARS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345109(SQL.90).aspx). You should decide your policy if you allow 2 connections or 2 sessions.

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge this is not possible through the SQL Server Security implementation itself.

You can however, globally configure the maximum number of connections to SQL Server.

I believe would need to control/filter/screen all connections to SQL Server, externally to the database engine, in order to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it declaratively on the server side. You could certainly do it in tsql code if you want to trust the application to enforce itself.